# Finding Which Points (with radius) Intersects Another Given Point (with radius)

Tags: mysql

I have a list of locations with points - and a range/radius defined in kilometers.

How do I find which of those intersect with a given point and radius?

Distance between points is easy, but I'm confused on this one.

Row 1 might be Lat/Lng @ 10 kilometers, row 2 might be Lat/Lng @ 3 kilometers.

I need to select which of those circles has any part overlapping a Lat/Lng @ say 23 kilometers.

I could pre-calculate and store an equivalent 4 point polygon for each of the records if that is the only way to do it.

Comment: Calculate the distance between points. Compare it with the sum of radiuses.

Comment: Thanks, but are you suggesting checking the sum of the radii after the query or during the query somehow using HAVING? I need  to do this as efficiently as possible with a clean result set w/o any need for post-processing.

Comment: In the query, in WHERE clause. `.. WHERE ST_Distance(t1.point1, t2.point) <= t1.radius + t2.radius ..`. Or maybe even in ON clause.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work via HAVING since it was easier that way for me to also retain/return those values in the result set. Really appreciate your suggestion that got me there as I just couldnt see the forest thru the trees at that point.